# Можно ли поменять VS Professional на Community

Tags: visual-studio

Можно ли поменять VS Professional на Community?
Не хочу удалять свою VS, у меня там нужные файлы, да и устанавливать геморно.
Можно ли как-то поменять версию без удаления Professional?

Comment: ¿а в чем проблема использовать professional дальше?

Comment: В инсталлере вроде можно установить любую версию

Comment: @user7860670, возможно, триал закончился.

Comment: Какие именно нужные файлы? Если код, то код он не трогает. В установщике есть импорт/экспорт конфигурации под кнопкой `Дополнительно`